# git already up-to-date but not same contents on multiple computers

Tags: git, push, pull

I have two computers that have git repository cloned.

When I type git push or git pull on either computer, it says "Already up-to-date"
However some files are missing from computer B which are present in computer A.

What's going on here?

```
on computer A, last 'git pull' showed    2478117..c6f8168  master     -> origin/master  
on computer B, last 'git push' showed  2478117..c6f8168  master -> master
```

Comment: What's the output of `git status` on both these machines?

Comment: Does A pull from B? Which files are there in one repo and not in the other? Make an example...

Comment: # On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean) ... 
topDir/someDir/someFile are in one computer but not in other

Comment: Are the pulls on the two machines actually using the same remotes?

Comment: Would bet `git status` on computer B returns something unexpected.